# How do I get the auth token from api.ai to send message to slack?

Tags: dialogflow-es, diagflow

I have a case where I need to create a Bot in Slack that my users can use conversational language to get information out of my web app in real time. The scenario goes something like:

User asks the bot something like: @hrbot How many employees are in the Finance department?

Bot send the string to API.AI/ diagflow to resolve into a JSON request

API.AI sends the JSON request to my Web App endpoint via webhook to get the answer

Answer is returned to user's Slack channel

Question:
1. How do I get the auth token from api.ai to send message to slack?

Answer (score 0):

With Dialogflow ([formerly API.AI](https://blog.dialogflow.com/post/apiai-new-name-dialogflow-new-features/)) you provide a webhook (a HTTPS URL where your server is) and Dialogflow will send a HTTPS request to your webhook when requests come to your Dialogflow agent.  You can enable the Slack integration in your Dialogflow agent through the [web interface](https://console.dialogflow.com) and all requests from Slack will be sent to your Dialogflow agent and (if you configure it) to your webhook with NLU information and the original request from Slack.

Information about the request that is sent to your webhook is documented here: dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#request if you respond to the request the response will be forwarded to the user that trigger the request. The response format is documented here: dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#response

Comment: Thanks - what is the NLU information - does that allow me to send information from my server back to the slack user who triggered the request ?

Comment: Information in the request is documented here: https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#request if you respond to the request the response will be forwarded to the user that trigger the request.  The response format is documented here: https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#response

Comment: Great to hear!  Just added my last comment to the answer for others.  Please mark as correct/upvote if you found it helpful.